# Table Column Names - NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, database, javadb

I am using NetBeans to build a Desktop App. I'm using JavaDB as the database. I need a column named "Date" . However , I get an error whenever I try to name a column that. Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance .

P.S I'm a newbie

Comment: @sameepkaul, please post the error message. It is likely that the column name "Date" is not allowed (Date being a common data type). But no one can help you much if you don't post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Date is a reserved word. You need to name it something else. For example, a name for the type of date it is like DATE_CREATED

Comment: Thanks a lot , thats what I figured as well. I don't mind changing the name of the column . But when the application is initialized , the column names in the data area of the application frame are the same as the column names in the table. Is there any way to change the column names in the application interface ?     

Thanks once again for your reply.